# Diamond problem with interfaces

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance, diamond-problem

I am using many abstract classes which define only pure virtual functions plus a virtual (non pure) destructor.

Is it still ok to have a diamond inheritance structure without using virtual inheritance? (I'd like to make sure that there are no problems even if some programmer does not know he should use virtual inheritance.) What's a good resource which gives a short but complete overview of this topic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't. Without virtual inheritance, the inheritance graph just isn't a diamond. If `Derived` inherits from `Left` and `Right`, and both derive non-virtually from `Base`, then there will be two `Base` subobjects per `Derived` object.

Comment: what if Base only has pure virtual methods?

Comment: You'd still have two copies. That means you can get two different `Base*` values from casting a `Derived*`. And consider a common vtable implementation: both `Base` suobjects would have their own vptr.

Answer (score 6):

Virtual inheritance is the mechanism by which you get a diamond - if you don't use virtual inheritance then you two different copies of the common base class - which isn't really a diamond any more and probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

[This faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/multiple-inheritance.html) provides good answers to multiple inheritance with examples.

For the diamond, you have to have virtual inheritance.